# Merging query records into one

Tags: sql, database

I really could use some help with this headache ...

Let's have a table with football players like this:

```
ID|Name|TeamID
1 |X   |10
2 |Y   |11
3 |Z   |12
etc.
```

and a table with team matches like this:

```
Home|Away|Result
10  |11  |0
10  |12  |1
10  |13  |1
etc.
```

what I would like to accomplish is to get a result set looking like this:

```
HomePlayer1|HomePlayer2|HomePlayer3|AwayPlayer1|AwayPlayer2|AwayPlayer3|Result
x          |y          |z          |a          |b          |c          |1
etc.
```

What approach should I take? The number of players in both teams is, let's say, constant. Is it something I can do in RDB with no hard feelings or should I think about it differently?

Comment: The technical term is to **pivotize** a table. But PIVOT operations are not part of standard SQL as far as I remember.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whilst it is possible in a SQL statement, dependant upon which RDBMS you're using, you'd be better off, in my mind, doing this procedurally, whether it be though a procedural SQL implementation E.G. Oracle's PL/SQL, or by connecting to a database from an application, E.G. a Java application etc.

Once you're in either your procedural SQL or application layer, it's simply a case of looping through the results of your query and building your result string.

Comment: OK, I was afraid that constructing that kind of SQL statement would be a huge waste of time and resources, so thank you for clearing that up!

Comment: It would be nice if there was a standard SQL way to combine data from multiple db records into a single output record. But there isn't. Some flavors of SQL have custom clauses that you can put on a SELECT to do this, but it's often messy. If at all practical, yes, just do it in code.